# Sqoop error on trying to connect to Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sqoop

I am trying to import a table data from mysql using sqoop. However, when I do so, I get a bad handshake error. Many online forums indicated the issue is with the mysql conf file. However, I dont see the bind address entry in the conf file. Here is the error that I see when ever I try to run the command `sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoop --username hadoop -P`. hadoop is the database I am trying to connect to and the username too is hadoop.

```
18/04/24 17:06:53 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL
streaming resultset.

18/04/24 17:06:53 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation

18/04/24 17:06:53 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement:
java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure: Bad handshake

java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure: Bad handshake
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.connectionInit(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.Connection.connectionInit(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:904)
```

Comment: Did you set all rights for your user hadoop? Something like this “ GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'hadoop'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;”

Answer (score 0):

you can not use "list-database" if you have already mentioned a database on the serverIP i-e "--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/**hadoop**".
try using the same sqoop invocation command with out the database name "hadoop" then call "list-database".
Also keep in mind this is using a driver in your sqoop invocation but first you or your system admin must put the specific driver in sqoop directory in 'lib' folder.
Hope this helps!